# Converting QString to float gives me errors

Tags: c++, qt, floating-point, qstring

I'm trying to convert a string to float  and vice versa but the compiler complains about it. In the editor I get `implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'float' to 'double'`. but I'm not converting a float to double at least not as far as I know.

```
C:\Qt\5.13.0\mingw73_64\include\QtCore\qstring.h:649: error: 'double QString::toFloat(bool*) const' cannot be overloaded
     double toFloat(bool *ok=nullptr) const;
            ^~~~~~~
```

And right below it:

```
C:\Qt\5.13.0\mingw73_64\include\QtCore\qstring.h:648: error: with 'float QString::toFloat(bool*) const'
     float toFloat(bool *ok=nullptr) const;
           ^~~~~~~
```

is what i get but I don't know why. The only thing I can imagine right now is that c++ can't tell if which version of `toFloat` I'm trying to use. The compiler points me out in the QString class where I can see two versions of `toFloat` that are identical except for the return type. I seriously have no clue how to solve this so I'd like some guidance on what I should add here to get it resolved.

```
else if (btnId == "=") {
 QRegExp separator("[(+|-|/|*)]");
    QStringList data = displayText.split(separator);

    bool ok = false;
    float result = 0.0;

    while (!data.isEmpty()) {
        QString str = data[0];
        data.pop_front();

        if (str == "+" || str == "-" || str == "/" || str == "*")
        {
            QString str2 = data[0];
            data.pop_front();

            if (str == "+") {
                double tmpF = str2.toFloat(&ok);
                result += tmpF;
            }
            else if (str == "-") {
                double tmpF = str2.toFloat(&ok);
                result -= tmpF;
            }
            else if (str == "/") {
                double tmpF = str2.toFloat(&ok);
                result /= tmpF;
            }
            else if (str == "*") {
                double tmpF = str2.toFloat(&ok);
                result *= tmpF;
            }
        }

        displayText.setNum(result, 'g', 6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading at the class documentation I found out that

`double toFloat(bool *ok=nullptr) const;`

shouldn't exist.

So in qstring.h I changed this:

```
float toFloat(bool *ok=nullptr) const;
double toFloat(bool *ok=nullptr) const;
```

to this:

```
float toFloat(bool *ok=nullptr) const;
double toDouble(bool *ok=nullptr) const;
```

And my program stopped complaining and ran fine.

QT Version is 5.13 (In case it matters: Windows Installation) .

Comment: This is very curious. How did you end up with that kind of header file? It shouldn't ever compile, as return type is not part of function signature in C++, so overloads can't differ only by their return type at all... Do you perhaps have some funny `#define` macros or something?

Comment: Be as it may, something is clearly botched with your Qt SDK installation. There may be other funny stuff then, too. I would reinstall if I were you... And check if the new install is ok.

Comment: Where did you get that qstring.h header???  https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstring.h.html#752

Comment: @MaximPaperno and hyde,  I just installed QT the normal way and didn't touch anything on it.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm not converting a float to double at least not as far as I
>   know.

yes you are, you do this:

```
 double tmpF = str2.toFloat(&ok);
```

which implicitly "turns" the float to tmpF before assigning it...

try casting before

```
auto x{str2.toFloat(&ok)};   
if(ok)
    double tmpF = static_cast<double>(x);
```

Comment: Well, you're right by reading my question which the code on it is the wrong version.
I actually didn't convert a float to double, I copy pasted the code while messing with it. 
And it ended up like that. In that particular instance I was changing everything to double to see if that would work but somehow pasted the code half way there. 
Sorry for that. I'll edit it.